# unable to calculate geohash from a large geometry

Tags: postgis

I am trying to insert a large buffer in the `city` table.

```
    INSERT INTO city (geom) (
    SELECT
    st_buffer(ST_multi(ST_union(geom)),
    10.0) FROM santa_clara_county);
```

In the `city` table I have a trigger defined which calculates geohash. During the insert I got the following error.

```
    [XX000] ERROR: Geohash requires inputs in decimal degrees, got 
    (6.06788e+06 1.78535e+06, 6.35495e+06 2.00181e+06).
    Where: PL/pgSQL function centroid_perimeter_area_trigger() line 6 
    at assignment
```

The same error remains when I remove the `st_buffer` and try to insert `st_multi` 
Does anyone know what cause the problem?

Comment: Please post the trigger code with the Geohash function call in it. The code you have posted is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your data is not in decimal degrees, ie. it should be between +/-180 longitude and +/-90 latitude.

You probably need to reproject your input data to EPSG:4326 before geohashing it.

Comment: Thank you @Ian Turton, this was the case. I didn't know that st_geohash works only with 4326 geometries